# Using connect-history-api-fallback' ,but not sure how to implement in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nginx, npm, vuejs2

When i refresh the page in vuejs, i get nginx error for tht I am using connect-history-api-fallback' ,but not sure how to implement in vuejs , i see that its usage in app.js with middleware server,how do we use in a standalone app in vuejs

Comment: BTW, if the below answer helped you, you can accept it. See [How do I reward a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do it in 2 ways.

1. with just nginx (nginx configuration) (For full nginx config check [this link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx))

   ```
   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
   ```
2. using express like server (server.js file with connect-history-api-fallback)

   ```
    const express = require('express');
    const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');const app = express();
    app.use(history());
    app.use(express.static('src'));app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile('src/index.html');
    });app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
   ```

--in your router you need to use history mode, follow this [vuejs history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Follow this blog for reference  https://medium.com/swlh/using-vue-routers-history-mode-6d9395e8122e